# "I have managed to pull off only two topics."

Tags: sentence-construction

"I have managed to pull off only two topics."
Is this phrase correct? As manage and pull-off has the same meaning.

Comment: We were doubtful the plan would succeed, but he managed to pull it off (Webster).

Answer (score 1):

The two verbs do overlap.

To "pull something off" means to succeed in doing it; the phrase is often used in situations where the expectation was failure, not success, or where the task, when thought about, seems more daunting in retrospect than it did to begin with.

To "manage to do something" means to do it, perhaps accidentally, perhaps in a clumsy way, perhaps in a manner which could not be repeated again at will. The person who accomplished the thing has no mastery of it.

Comment: Could you please correct this phrase for me then?

Comment: What do you mean by "then"?

Comment: As this phrase is wrong ..could you please correct it for me?

Comment: Who said it was wrong?

Comment: you said that two verbs are overlapping that's why i thought it is wrong...

Comment: That their meanings overlap does not make their use in tandem ungrammatical.  They combine to create the idea that the success in those two topics was perhaps only a middling success, an accomplishment without mastery.